# how to make a function to change the text back and forward

Tags: button, addtextchangedlistener

I just want to change the button text

```
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
$("#reset').on("click", function () {
this.textContent  = "Loading....";
setTimeOut("this.textContent = " Reset", 2000)
}
```

after I clicked it will change the text to Loading and in few second it turn back to Reset.
I tried to add text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery.

Just this:

```html
<button id="reset" onclick="this.textContent = 'Loading...'; setTimeout( e => this.textContent = 'Reset', 2000 );">Reset</button>
```